# Ionic Native File Opener plugin won't open .pdf files with default app in Android

Tags: android, cordova, pdf, ionic-framework

I'm quite new to the whole Ionic and Cordova environment and I'm having some trouble trying to open a .pdf file from the Ionic app with the default native pdf reader.

Here is my markup:

```
<ion-scroll overflow-scroll="true" scrollX="true">
<ion-card>
  <ion-card-content>
    <a href="assets/sheets/clicks_bs.pdf">
      <img src="assets/sheets/clicks_bs.jpg"/>
    </a>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
<ion-card>
  <ion-card-content>
    <a href="assets/sheets/makro.pdf">
      <img src="assets/sheets/makro.png" />
    </a>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
<ion-card>
  <ion-card-content>
    <a href="assets/sheets/picknpay_bs.pdf">
      <img src="assets/sheets/picknpay_bs.jpg"/>
    </a>
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
</ion-scroll>
```

Here is my component:

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Slides } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FileOpener } from '@ionic-native/file-opener';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers: [FileOpener]
})
export class HomePage {

  @ViewChild('storebrands') slides: Slides;
  constructor(private fileOpener: FileOpener ) {
    let i = 0;
    setInterval(() => {
      this.goToSlide(i);
      if (i === 8)
        i = 0;
      else
        i++;
    }, 5000);

    this.fileOpener.open('assets/sheets/*.pdf', 'application/pdf')
      .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
      .catch(e => console.log('Error openening file', e));

   }
}
```

I have imported the file opener and injected it into the constructor and I've added it as a provider, however when I try clicking on the image in Android, it does nothing. Can someone please give some insight on why it isn't opening in the default .pdf reader on a native device.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did u add the plugin first?

Comment: Yes, the plugin is available in node_modules

Comment: try command `cordova plugins ls` it should show the plugin entry there

Comment: cordova-plugin-console 1.0.5 "Console"

cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"

cordova-plugin-file-opener2 2.0.15 "File Opener2"

cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"

cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.2 "StatusBar"

cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"

ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"

Comment: oh! You cannot open pdf in asset folder using fileopener2... as it triggers external app to open the file. As the file is inside the App, external app cant access your app sandbox. The file should be in a accessible location like sd-card

Comment: Would that mean that the end user would need to download the .pdf file to their native device before they can view it? Do you have a code example please.

Comment: follow this tutorials http://www.gajotres.net/how-to-open-a-file-using-its-default-application-in-ionic-framework/

Comment: what you have to do is to copy the file intend to open to a common accessible location and call the fileopener2

Comment: Thanks @Nirus. I've done a quick work around for now and have the pdf files sitting on a server

Answer (score 0):

**Use DocumentViewer Plugin**

```
showDocument(pdff){
      const options: DocumentViewerOptions = {
        title: 'My PDF',
        openWith:   { enabled: true},
        bookmarks : {
          enabled : true
      },
      search : {
          enabled : true
      },
      autoClose: {
          onPause : true
      }
      }
      const imgeLocation = `${cordova.file.applicationDirectory}www/assets/imgs/${pdff}`;
      this.document.viewDocument(imgeLocation, 'application/pdf', options)
    }
```